# Transactional between two microservice

Tags: microservices

I thinking about the solution to solve problem such as transfer money across banks.
Let say I have two microservices namely A and B with separated database on each of them. I prefered 2PC and Saga but my thought have a bit difference, let I explain more. With each of microservice operation I would have **State** to keep track, in this case eg. *Created and Approved*. I would like some how two microservice **MUST** acknowledge state of each other before change state to Approved. Below are what I mean, I do not know what should do in step 5.

[image]

I would have a atomicity operation in **step 5**. Both microservice would have Approved state or none of them would have. I thought my expectation will generate a cyclic operations between two microservice, right?
Imagine like two bank transfering money is what I would like to achieve. I do not know whether what I am design and thinking is correct or not. Could you possibly give me some advise to address this kind of problem. Or give me some patterns which adapt this issue more efficiently.

Please ask me if my question not clear.

Comment: I thought that my thinking is a cyclic operations. I should not implement microservice in this way. After I observed the behavior when I transfer money between two bank. First bank open a ACID transaction to substract my money and post a message to gateway of another bank. Other bank will do another ACID transaction to added money for target user and update status, after period of time first bank will check status of message to make substract or refund to my account rely on transaction of second bank is success or not.